# Feature Engineering continue previous last value occuerence

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For the given dataframe

```
spark.createDataFrame([
  ("2019-06-24T07:29:22.000+0000", "Image Quality: 75"),
  ("2019-06-25T07:29:22.000+0000", "Start scan"),
  ("2019-06-26T07:29:22.000+0000", "Image Quality: 95"),
  ("2019-06-27T07:29:22.000+0000", "Start scan"),
  ("2019-06-28T07:29:22.000+0000", "Start scan")  
], ["ts", "message"])
```

I'm interested to engineer an image quality feature, i.e. compose the following dataframe.

```
+----------------------------+----------+-------------+
|ts                          |message   |image_quality|
+----------------------------+----------+-------------+
|2019-06-25T07:29:22.000+0000|Start scan|75           |
|2019-06-27T07:29:22.000+0000|Start scan|95           |
|2019-06-28T07:29:22.000+0000|Start scan|95           |
+----------------------------+----------+-------------+
```

I've attempted various combination of windows functions and subqueries but nothing seems to be reaching a workable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to carry forward last available Image quality till next available.

Can try something like below using `Window`:

*Assumptions from the given dataset: For any date, it will always start with `Image Quality: <some value>` and followed by `Start scan`*

**Imports and prepare dataset:**

```
# Import Window
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.show(10, False)
+----------------------------+-----------------+
|ts                          |message          |
+----------------------------+-----------------+
|2019-06-24T07:29:22.000+0000|Image Quality: 75|
|2019-06-25T07:29:22.000+0000|Start scan       |
|2019-06-26T07:29:22.000+0000|Image Quality: 95|
|2019-06-27T07:29:22.000+0000|Start scan       |
|2019-06-28T07:29:22.000+0000|Start scan       |
+----------------------------+-----------------+
```

Now split the `message` with `:` separator and creating `image_quality` column

```
df1 = df.withColumn('image_quality', f.split('message', ':')[1])
df1.show(10, False)
+----------------------------+-----------------+-------------+
|ts                          |message          |image_quality|
+----------------------------+-----------------+-------------+
|2019-06-24T07:29:22.000+0000|Image Quality: 75| 75          |
|2019-06-25T07:29:22.000+0000|Start scan       |null         |
|2019-06-26T07:29:22.000+0000|Image Quality: 95| 95          |
|2019-06-27T07:29:22.000+0000|Start scan       |null         |
|2019-06-28T07:29:22.000+0000|Start scan       |null         |
+----------------------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

**Define window with `orderBy` `ts` column**

**Note:** As we are interested in solution approach so didn't add any `partitionBy` column but If possible then always have `partitionBy`

Spark will also give below warning :

> WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all
>   data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance
>   degradation.

```
w_spec = Window.orderBy('ts')
```

**Final dataset prepare:**

Now, Apply `window` and find the last available image quality using `last('col', True)`. Here `True` will ignore the `null` values.

Also, filter the records and remove `Not like Image Quality` or `== Start scan`.

```
final_df = df1.withColumn('image_quality', f.coalesce('image_quality', f.last('image_quality', True).over(w_spec))) \
            .where(df1.message == 'Start scan')

final_df.show()

+--------------------+----------+-------------+
|                  ts|   message|image_quality|
+--------------------+----------+-------------+
|2019-06-25T07:29:...|Start scan|           75|
|2019-06-27T07:29:...|Start scan|           95|
|2019-06-28T07:29:...|Start scan|           95|
+--------------------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: This was exactly what I am was aiming at, thank you. Could you please elaborate on the partition warning message as my actual dataset will be ~300 million rows.

Comment: In your case, if you have only 2 columns in dataframe then I am not able to find out any combination of partition column that achieved the same result.

Comment: @MaximVeksler : Glad it helped. Alright, so warning says that data will be moved into one partition. It means that `no multiple partitions` hence (almost)`no concurrent tasks` from spark. Also, one partition with huge data in it will have overhead from memory, CPU, Shuffle etc prespective.As you have ~300M records its required to use `partitionBy`. Not sure if you have any other column which you can use as `Window` You can use any logical window based on data.